# How to make a readonly text box editable on mouse-over using J query

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a read-only text-box with text in it. How to  make it editable on mouse-over using J query ?

Comment: I wonder why it is readonly in the first place when a simple mouseover will unlock it. And I wonder what happens when I press TAB to get into the field.

Comment: Tomalak, Today I noticed a feature in g mail, where we can edit the contact information by just hovering your mouse over a text-box that contains the email address.The text-box becomes editable and user can edit the email address and can save it. So I was wondering how they are doing it.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$('#textbox_id').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).removeAttr('readonly');
});
```

Where `textbox_id` is the `id` of the text box.

**More Info:**

- http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/
- http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/